# Organizing types/namespaces within tree

Tags: f#

I'm working on a parsing engine as part of a personal project, and I'd like to expose certain .NET APIs to the parsed environment. I put together a very simple tagged union that allowed me to nest types, and put together a few functions that built up a tree of namespaces. Before going further, I decided I needed to refine the types I was using, and came up with this:

```
type Node =
    | Namespace of string * Node list

    | Class of string * Node list * System.Type
    | Interface of string * Node list * System.Type
    | Structure of string * Node list * System.Type
    | Enumeration of string * (string * Base.AnyInteger) list * System.Type

    | Property of string * System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
    | Field of string * System.Reflection.FieldInfo
    | Event of string * System.Reflection.EventInfo

    | Constructor of System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo
    | Function of string * System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    | Subroutine of string * System.Reflection.MethodInfo
```

`Base.AnyInteger` is another tagged union elsewhere that has cases for every .NET integer type except bigint. My expectation with these "Nodes" is that each one (except constructors) will contain their name in the string, a `Node list` containing any child nodes, and a reference to their `System.Type` or `System.Reflection.___Info` to provide additional information when needed. Last, I added the extra empty lines to help mentally align each level of nodes.

After defining a list of constraints that would have to be managed "in logic", I remembered that I'm not working with VB or C#, and that F#'s type system is better than what I'm used to. After about a half hour I came up with this:

```
type Lvl1 = Namespace of string * (Choice<Lvl1, Lvl2>) list

and Lvl2 =
    | Class of string * Choice<Lvl2, Lvl3, Constructor> list * System.Type
    | Structure of string * Choice<Lvl2, Lvl3, Constructor> list * System.Type
    | Interface of string * Choice<Lvl2, Lvl3> list * System.Type
    | Enumeration of string * (string * Base.AnyInteger) list * System.Type

and Lvl3 =
    | Property of string * System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
    | Field of string * System.Reflection.FieldInfo
    | Event of string * System.Reflection.EventInfo
    | Function of string * System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    | Subroutine of string * System.Reflection.MethodInfo

and Constructor = System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo
```

This new set of types correctly describes what each node can contain, using the type system to enforce everything rather than just implying how the levels are arranged with empty lines. Now nodes from Lvl1 can contain children from Lvl1 or Lvl2, nodes from Lvl2 can contain children from Lvl2 or Lvl3 (Classes and Structures may also contain Constructors), and nodes at Lvl3 cannot contain any children.

Now that I've used the type system to make sure I can't accidentally add a Namespace node inside a Class node, are there any other obvious changes I should be making here? I'll also admit I was originally using list references for each list of child nodes, because it made it easier to reason about in an imperative way; I've since revisited my code and have removed `ref` and started making use of map/fold/etc.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this? The built-in reflection APIs already provide a graph of types and members (e.g. `Type` has members for accessing methods, properties, and fields).

Comment: Part of the motivation is wanting to force myself to use the type system and define more complex types; the other half is that I'd like a tree of objects that I can walk with just a fully-qualified type name without checking all of the members (methods, properties, subtypes, etc.) for something with the right name. Although now that I explain myself, it sounds like what I'm doing is an exercise in futility.

Comment: It might be fine, but this is a lot of effort just to replace something that already works. One possibility, that's less redundant, would be to create a facade for the built-in reflection APIs that allows pattern matching using active patterns, much like the [Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370259.aspx) module provides for F# types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Node
```

I agree with you that this is too weakly typed.

---

```
type Lvl1
and Lvl2
and Lvl3
```

I don't like the naming here. The name `Lvl2` doesn't really say much. Better names would be something like `Namespace`, `Type` and `Member` (or maybe `TypeMember`).

---

```
Choice<Lvl2, Lvl3, Constructor>
```

I think that constructor is logically a type member, just like a property or function. So I would make `Constructor` another case in the `Lvl3` (or `Member`) union. I think making the model simpler is worth having the possibility of a constructor in an interface.

With that change, `struct`, `class` and `interface` look exactly the same, so I would refactor it further by combining the three cases into one (called something like `ComplexType`), and distinguishing between them by an additional field (something like `ComplexTypeKind`).

Also, I would encode the possibility of a nested type by adding a case to `Lvl3` (a.k.a. `Member`). But if you keep your current design, you should remove `Lvl2` from the `Interface` case, because interfaces can't have nested types.

---

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
```

There is no need to repeat the namespace name, you can `open` it.

---

```
Property of string * System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
```

Why do you keep the name, when it's already accessible through the `PropertyInfo`? This question applies to most of your cases.

Comment: Thanks for the new names, I was drawing a blank when I named them Lvl{1,2,3}.  
I'd probably rather keep complexity around constructors because it means the type system enforces the lack of them in interfaces (as an aside, VB [allows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2805251/1385230) nested types within interfaces; as part of a VB team, I'll have to deal with that). However with Class/Structure I could combine them and use `Type.IsValueType` to differentiate.  
The names are duplicated primarily to ease poking around values while debugging. I'll pull them once I've got the rest of the code in place.